Convergence rate maximum iid random variables
I know that for random variables $X_i$ with distribution $F$ (which does not depend on $n$) and finite second moment that,
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\max_{1\le i\le n}X_i \xrightarrow p0.
$$
However, for many random variables with finite second moment this is not tight, for the normal distribution for example, the maximum is asymptotically $\sqrt{2\log n}$. Can this convergence rate $\sqrt{n}$ be improved, to something like $n^\epsilon$? And which distribution has the fastest growing maximum?

is this like weak law of large numbers but max instead of average? or what?

You'll need to look at extreme value theory. It completely characterizes the rate of convergence of the sample maxima. For example, you have something like $a_n(\max_i X_i - b_n)$ converges in law to a non-degenerate distribution $G$. Then clearly, you can see that $a_n\max_i X_i$ has an asymptotic law as $a_nb_n+ G$. Hence if you multiply by $c_n$, the limit law is $c_n(a_nb_n+G)$. Take the largest $c_n$ such that this limit is $0$, then the corresponding factor for $\max_i X_i$ would be $a_nc_n$.
